# two Position Fixed on top

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide

I want to show **two divs** with **position fixed on top**.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="notice"> 
    <p>Announcement bla bla bla...</p>
        <span>CLOSE</span>
</div>
<div id="top">
    <p>search here</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#notice {
    width:100%; height:50px; background:#FFFFFF; position:fixed; top:0; z-index:1;
}
#top {
    width:100%; height:50px; background:#197ac5; position:fixed; top:50px; z-index:1;
}
```

---

I'm trying to make it when i click on `<span id="notice">`, then it will hide it, **but also** make `#top` replace position to `top:0px;`.

Is that possible to do this?

```
$("#notice span").click(function() {
        $("#notice").hide();
});
```

---

I look on http://www.ebay.com, and they had the same #notice but with no `position:fixed;`.

When I click "Close" on the eBay notice, it will hide it **and will never show again** in another page.

But, in my website, when I click the close button,

1. It *will* hide that #notice, but when I go to another page, it will show.
2. `#top` did not move to replace `position:fixed; top:0px;`.

What's wrong with my code?

---

**FINAL SOLUTION inspired by Marian**

Thank you very much for all of u guys! especially Marian!

i ended up with this awesome plugins https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

```
$('#notice p').click(function() {
    $("#notice").hide();
    Cookies.set('actionbar', 'hide');
});

var actionbar = Cookies.set('actionbar');
  if (actionbar == 'hide') {
    $("#notice").hide();
  };
```

Thanks Marian You save my life Tonight! i hope this post will be useful for all of the other guy :)

Comment: would be a bit more readable without all the bold :-)

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the second part of your question!

Comment: @tony, im sorry about that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#notice span").click(function() {
   $("#notice").hide();
   $("#top").animate({"top": "0"}, 600);
});
```

Should work for your animation! To cache a function you can use a cookie something like this:

```
$(function() {
 if( document.cookie.indexOf( "runOnce" ) < 0 ) {
 // function to fire once only 
 document.cookie = "runOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
});
```

To keep it easy I would hide `#notice` on default, and show it using jQuery, until you have clicked `#notice span`:

```
<style>#notice {display: none;}</style>

$("#notice").show();
```

To put it all together (on a mobile device without testing it):

```
$(function() {
if( document.cookie.indexOf( "runOnce" ) < 0 ) {
     $("#notice").show();
     $("#notice span").click(function() {
        $("#notice").hide();
        $("#top").animate({"top": "0"}, 600);
        document.cookie = "runOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks Marian for ur answer!, i try ur solution, first, it works, but after using cookie, not working anymore if( document.cookie.indexOf( "runOnce" ) < 0 ) {

Comment: What do you mean by not working anymore? Can you describe what should happen, that does not happen? Does the `#notice` div still pop on load?

Comment: Thanks Marian u r da real MVP!

Answer (score 0):

First thing

```
$("#notice span").click(function() {
        $("#notice").hide();
        $("#top").css("top","0px");
});
```

Second thing

You must have a cache technique for it to appear never again after clicked.
Have a look : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 :
You must use cookies to check if user closes a notice ( Or sessions ) [ Cookies can done by jQuery but Sessions require server.] 
Question 2 : 
You can create a container div and position it fixed on top then use position relative on child elements ( Notice boxes ) after you hide a notice it automatically goes to that place.
Hope it helps.